# How can i solve this System of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

**My Problem** is this given system of differential equations: $$y_{1}^{\prime}=y_{1}-y_{2}$$
$$y_{2}^{\prime}=5y_{1}+3y_{2}$$ I am looking for the solution.

**My Approach was**: this seems to be a system of first-order differential equations. they are ordinary differential equations.

I built the corresponding matrix:

$$\underbrace{\pmatrix{ y_1^{\prime} \\ y_2^{\prime}}}_{\large{ {\vec y^{\prime}}}} = \underbrace{\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 5 & 3}}_{\large{\mathbf A}}\underbrace{\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}}_{\large{\vec y}}$$ Now i need to find the eigenvalues of this matrix in order to determine the eigenvectors And here i am stuck. I failed in finding the eigenvalues. Every eigenvalue i find seems to be no number. so cannot calculate with it. But if the eigenvalues are anything other than numbers, (for example a complex number) how can i find the solution for the system of differential equations in this case?

Comment: The eigenvalues are complex numbers.

Comment: Don't be so deterred by the fact that the eigenvalues are complex numbers :)

Comment: *if the eigenvalues are anything other than numbers, (for example a complex number)*. Complex numbers **are** numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\5&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
is correct. Note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\5&3\end{bmatrix}^2
=4\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\5&3\end{bmatrix}
-8\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}
$$
Solving the recurrence yields
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\5&3\end{bmatrix}^k
&=\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2+i&i\\-5i&2-i\end{bmatrix}(2+2i)^k\\
&+\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2-i&-i\\5i&2+i\end{bmatrix}(2-2i)^k\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
This gives us
$$
\begin{align}
\exp\left(t\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\5&3\end{bmatrix}\right)
&=\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2+i&i\\-5i&2-i\end{bmatrix}e^{t(2+2i)}\\
&+\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2-i&-i\\5i&2+i\end{bmatrix}e^{t(2-2i)}\\
&=2\,\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2+i&i\\-5i&2-i\end{bmatrix}e^{(2+2i)t}\right)\\
&=\frac{e^{2t}}{2}\left(\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\cos(2t)
+\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\5&1\end{bmatrix}\sin(2t)\right)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}y_1(t)\\y_2(t)\end{bmatrix}=\frac{e^{2t}}{2}\left(\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\cos(2t)
+\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\5&1\end{bmatrix}\sin(2t)\right)\begin{bmatrix}y_1(0)\\y_2(0)\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Why did you take $\Re$?

Comment: @Kaster: Because the series for the exponential is broken into two conjugate sums by $(3)$ and $z+\bar{z}=2\,\mathrm{Re}(z)$. I added an extra line to $(4)$ to hopefully make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation, we get $y_2=y_1-y'_1$. By substituting this into second equation, we get $y''_1-4y'_1+8y_1=0$, and after solving characteristic equation ($a^2-4a+8=0\Rightarrow a=2\pm 2i$), we get 
$$y_1=C_1e^{2x}\cos{2x}+C_2e^{2x}\sin{2x},$$
$$y_2=y_1-y'_1=-(2C_2+C_1)e^{2x}\cos{2x}+(2C_1-C_2)e^{2x}\sin{2x}.$$